# How to get front end servers from sharepoint 2010 farm

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have an requirement of getting the front end web server in SharePoint farm.This is the code for getting it.

```
SPFarm myFarm = SPFarm.Local;
SPServerCollection serverColl = myFarm.Servers;
if (serverColl != null && serverColl.Count > 0)
{
foreach (SPServer spserver in serverColl)
{
  //get exceute
}
}
```

May I know this the appropriate way to achieve this or any other suitable way to achieve it ?

Comment: What you intend to do via above will work fine as well and its documented to work that way. You can also achieve similar stuff from Powershell as well.

Answer (score 3):

What are you asking, exactly? You're like 95% of the way there. On the spserver variable, just call the `Role` and/or `Name` properties, as such:

```
    foreach (SPServer spserver in serverColl)
    {
       spserver.Role // will be WebFrontEnd, Application, etc.
    }
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spserverrole.aspx) for the possible values of the SPServerRole enumeration.

Comment: For me it's working fine with my existing code ,just I need to know whether there is a better approach for this to achieve this functionality ?

Comment: This would be the best way; this is exactly what those methods/properties/enumerations are there for. Otherwise, you're looking at re-inventing the wheel for a solved problem.

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply and for e.g say If there are 3 front end servers connected to a farm, How can I check currently in which server my code is get exceuting ?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's a whole other question, and a bit of a rabbit hole. Is it a sandboxed solution, or not? What is your farm topology: App Servers, WFE's? (not asking you literally)